# ActiveStorage download all

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

I use ActiveStorage recently, and I would like to know if there is a way to download all the attached files in one time. For example I have a Post, with many photos, and the user can download all the photos attached to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Download all attached photos to a post in a ZIP file as follow:

```rb
def download_zip
  send_zip Post.photos
end
```

You have to use the following gem

```rb
gem 'active_storage-send_zip'
```

Do not forget to add to your controller:

```rb
include ActiveStorage::SendZip
```

Reference:
https://github.com/madeindjs/active_storage-send_zip

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this with recursion + `ActiveStorage::Blob#open`

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.2.1/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-open

Sample code:

```rb
def download_all(attachments, files = [], &block)
  if attachments.empty?
    yield files
    return
  end

  attachments.first.open do |file|
    files << file
    method(__method__)[attachments[1, attachments.length - 1], files, &block]
  end
end
```

Usage:

```rb
download_all(record.attachments) do |files|
  pp files
end
```

Note that files will be **automatically removed** after the block terminates, you must process all files inside the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the client side, having the url of the documents in the following way using npm jszip

```
  const handleDownloadDocuments = async () => {
    if (!documents.length || isDownloading) return;
    try {
      setIsDownloading(true);
      const zip = new JSZip();
      // Fetch the documents and add them to the zip file
      await Promise.all(
        documents.map(async (document) => {
          const response = await axios.get(document.url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
          zip.file(document.name, response.data);
        })
      );
      // Generate the zip file
      const zipBlob = await zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' });
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(zipBlob);
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute("download", `${project?.attributes?.slug}.zip`);
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
      document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error({error});
    }
    finally {
      setIsDownloading(false);
    }
  };
```